# I want to implement the css grid template areas for the following collection of div but its showing no effect at all

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, grid, css-grid

**I want to implement the css grid template areas for the following collection of div but its showing no effect at all**

*Parent file*

```
 const datas = [{
      tech: RCT,
      value: 'react'
    },{
      tech:JS ,
      value: 'Javascript'
    },{
      tech: Node,
      value: 'NodeJS'
    },{
      tech: HTML,
      value: 'HTML5'
    },{
      tech:Mongo ,
      value: 'MongoDB'
    },{
      tech:CSS ,
      value: 'CSS3'
    },{
      tech: EXP,
      value: 'ExpressJS'
    },{
      tech:GIT ,
      value: 'Git'
    } ]



    <div className="tech-up">
    {datas.map((data) =>  (
    <SkillItem  inner= {data}/>
    ))}
    </div>
```

**    Child file where the datas are passed as props**

```
const {tech, value} = inner

  return (
    <div className="text-center flex flex-col justify-between items-center">
      <img src={tech} alt={value} className={`w-16 ${value}`}/>
      <p>{value}</p>
    </div>
  )
```

**PS: I use tailwind css as the library for other components but tried to do custom grid on this one but it doesn't support**

```
.react{
  grid-area: 'react'
}

.Javascript{
  grid-area: 'js'
}

.NodeJS{
  grid-area: 'node'
}

.HTML5{
  grid-area: 'html'
}

.MongoDB{
  grid-area: 'mongo'
}

.CSS3{
  grid-area: 'css'
}

.ExpressJS{
  grid-area: 'express'
}

.Git{
  grid-area: 'git';
} 


.tech-up{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 14px;
  grid-row-gap: 14px;
  grid-template-areas: "react sth  js sth  node sth  html"
  "sth mongo sth  css sth  express sth "
  "sth sth sth git sth sth sth "
  ;
}
```

Comment: You are using `flex` classes on your items, so maybe you are just overriding layout with them (`.flex .flex-col`). Try to check in developer tools what styles are really rendered. If this will not help you - then provide working example of your code

Comment: Also, you are adding template areas `.Git`, `.CSS3` etc. to the image **inside the item**, but need to use it **on the item**

Comment: @VladislavAkhmetvaliyev thank u so much man you saved a lot of time